# How do create a formatted json with Java?

Tags: java, json, string

So given these arbitrary variables

```
String name = "bob";
List<String> hobby = new ArrayList<String>();
hobby.add("walk");
hobby.add("gym");
hobby.add("football");
```

How do I output a String json? Example of above

```
{
    "name": "bob",
    "hobby": [
        "walk",
        "gym",
        "football"
    ]

}
```

I've tried JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); but with that it wasn't properly formatted the way I wanted.

Comment: What json library are you using? And how are you converting the said objects to json?

Comment: I used import org.json.JSONObject; And as for converting I just put all the values in it I couldn't get the list to work though.

Comment: What is the name of the library? Did you write `JSONObject` yourself?

Comment: This might be a stupid question... but how do I check? JSONObject jsonKey = new JSONObject();
        jsonKey.put("name", name); the import let me use that, is about all I know

Comment: What IDE are you using? Is this android?

Comment: eclipse IDE latest version (not android)

Comment: Are you using the android sdk in your code?

Comment: Nothing is android in my code no

Comment: What is current output in your console?

Comment: I'm just going to guess that you are using: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java, according to this [site](https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json)

Comment: {"name": "bob", "hobbies": ["walk", "gym", "football"]}

Comment: If you are indeed using the library I mentioned above, then you may want to look at the `JSONWriter` or `JSONStringer` classes. See [docs](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html). The JSONObject class has a [`toString`](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString-int-) method which allows you to set the indent level - that may be of interest to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to handle the list - **hobby** - by yourself to print it with newline. But with the help of `Gson`(Google Gson), you can print them as you expected as follows.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("name", name);
jsonObj.put("hobby", hobby);

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonObj.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(json));
```

Then the console out is going to be

```
{
  "name": "bob",
  "hobby": [
    "walk",
    "gym",
    "football"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATED**

If you use `writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()` in Jackson2 library, it seems not to print Json array as same as `Gson`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object jsonObj1 = mapper.readValue(jsonObj.toString(), Object.class);
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonObj1));
```

Console output:

```
{
  "name" : "bob",
  "hobby" : [ "walk", "gym", "football" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use fasterxml jackson, it would be very easy.
**UPD1:** output with default pretty printer.

```
@Test
public void test01() {

    String name = "bob";
    List<String> hobby = new ArrayList<String>();
    hobby.add("walk");
    hobby.add("gym");
    hobby.add("football");

    // create a class with name and hobby property
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    demo.setName(name);
    demo.setHobby(hobby);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(demo);
        System.out.println(result);
        //{"name":"bob","hobby":["walk","gym","football"]}
        String prettyResult = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(demo);
        System.out.println(prettyResult);
//            {
//                "name" : "bob",
//                "hobby" : [ "walk", "gym", "football" ]
//            }
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class Demo {
    private String name;
    private List<String> hobby;
    //getter/setter
}
```